# NotSupportedException for LINQ Queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am trying to get a list of a database table called oracleTimeCards whose employee id equals to the employeeID in employees list. Here is what I wrote:

```
LandornetSQLEntities db = new LandornetSQLEntities();

List<OracleEmployee> employees = db.OracleEmployees.Where(e => e.Office.Contains(officeName) && e.IsActive == true).Distinct().ToList();

var oracleTimeCards = db.OracleTimecards.Where(c => employees.Any(e => c.PersonID == e.PersonID)).ToList();
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: "Here is what I wrote" -> "Anyone has any idea?". This is a non-sequitur. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: In the last line of the code, it throws NotSupportedException: Details : : Unable to create a constant value of type 'LandorResourceManagementTool.Models.OracleEmployee'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Entity Framework here. You can't embed calls to arbitrary LINQ extension methods inside your predicate, since EF might not know how to translate these to SQL.

Assuming you want to find all the timecards for the employees you found in your first query, you have two options. The simplest is to have a navigation property on your `Employee` class, named let's say `TimeCards`, that points to  a collection of time card records for the given employee. Here's how that would work:

```
var oracleTimeCards = employees
    .SelectMany(e => e.TimeCards)
    .ToList();
```

If you don't want to do this for whatever reason, you can create an array of employee IDs by evaluating your first query, and use this to filter the second:

```
var empIDs = employees
    .Select(e => e.PersonID)
    .ToArray();

var oracleTimeCards = db.OracleTimecards
    .Where(tc => empIDs.Contains(tc.PersonID))
    .ToList();
```